# Riley Riddle #8: Do aliens sparkle?

Tags: riddle

My middle, a self helper motivated
I end with a space filler, overrated
I start with an avatar of mischievery
In my entirety, I corrupt absolutely

Hint 1:

> This riddle references one of the two words in the title of a cult-classic past time. The title of this riddle references the other word.

Hint 2:

> The infix is a proper noun. The suffix is one of the most common words spoken and one of the least common words written. To some, the prefix is devlish (as opposed to demonic).

Comment: This one is pretty hard, maybe release a hint?

Comment: A hint for what, all four clues?

Comment: Or another line

Comment: So the title of a cult classic film?

Comment: There are lots of different kinds of past times :)

Comment: I've never heard cult classic used to refer to anything but a film.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cult_following

TV shows and video games are also listed. This particular clue is not a film, a tv show, or a video game, but the definition "A cult following is a group of fans who are highly dedicated to a work of culture, often referred to as a cult classic" definitely applies to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is it

> Imperium?

I start with an avatar of mischievery

> An IMP

My middle, a self helper motivated

> I got nothing here. Credit to @El-Guest for finding PERIU, an award winning author.

I end with a space filler, overrated.

> Um

In my entirety, I corrupt absolutely

> An Imperium (Supreme or absolute power)

Comment: I'm willing to say you're right on the full word. Do you give up on the infix, or do you want to keep trying for it?

Comment: I think El-Guest got it?

Comment: Nope! They are on the right track but not quite.

Comment: They've got it now! I'm giving you the checkmark though since you got the whole word first :P. Now for the other references: The title is a reference to the cult classic board game Twilight Imperium, which is an epic space opera game featuring lots of aliens. The reference to sparkling is because the other word in the title, other than the word in the riddle, is Twilight. In Twilight, there are sparkling vampires, so no, the aliens don't sparkle. Also, in addition to writing The Power of Motivation, Periu also wrote 101 ways to Get Motivated, which is the book that inspired this riddle.

Comment: Great answer!! Glad I could help :D

Answer (score 2):

@Reibello has the correct answer, I'm just trying to play around with the infix.

Are you

> IMPERIUM?

My middle, a self helper motivated

> The award-winning speaker and author of The Power of Motivation, Omar PERIU.

I end with a space filler, overrated

> UM...this is a space filler.

I start with an avatar of mischievery

> IMP, a typical mischievous creature.

In my entirety, I corrupt absolutely

> IMPERIUM, meaning absolute power.

Comment: Nice try! The infix doesn't make sense though, and a lot of the extra information given in the hints don't apply. I'll say that you have the right inspiration for the full word clue, but the answer isn't quite that direct :P

Comment: Updated my answer to try to get the infix, @flashstorm

Comment: Getting closer! Remember that authors are referenced by their last name, not their first. Also, the word "motivated" is important. Important in over a hundred ways :P

Comment: Ahhhh now I think I got it! @flashstorm